# How can close the image file using FileStream

Tags: c#, image, file-io

I need to make image from canvas and from internet I find this code who works perfect. Is make the image and is good. But now I need to add some text in this new image and i think this is the problem. Sometimes is working, sometimes is throw me this exception. How can I close the image and change the image again. Or how can I change the image without is have exception.

```
int width = (int)(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * 0.75);
int height = (int)canvas.Height;

RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
width, (int)canvas.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
// needed otherwise the image output is black
canvas.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(width, height));
canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Size(width, height)));

renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

//JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
{
     encoder.Save(file);
}
```

This is what Exception I have:

> The process cannot access the file 'image.png' because it is being used by another process.

I try with `file.Close()`, I try without `file.Close()` `filename` is path to image file who create and then used and try delete

Here and my code This code is running every 1 second.

```
private void CreateSaveBitmap(Canvas canvas, string filename, string sensor)
{
    int width = (int)(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * 0.75);
    int height = (int)canvas.Height;

    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
         width, (int)canvas.Height,
         96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    // needed otherwise the image output is black
    canvas.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(width, height));
    canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Size(width, height)));

    renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

    //JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

    using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
    {
        encoder.Save(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    string head = SetHeadForPrintImage(sensor);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    g.DrawString(head, new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new PointF(200, 0));

    bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
    File.Delete(filename); // throw me exception
    File.Delete(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");
    bmp.Save(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: Closing a file, won't close immediately, so try adding Sleep to wait until its closed. But I think there should be away you can convert the renderBitmap to Bitmap without saving it into a file.

Comment: are you sure that image isn't open in a viewer when you get the exception? In addition, disable the antivirus

Comment: @AntiHeadshot with sleep again is throw me exception

Answer (score 1):

```
private void CreateSaveBitmap(Canvas canvas, string filename, string sensor)
{
    if(File.Exists(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg"))
    {
         File.Delete(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");
    }
    int width = (int)(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * 0.75);
    int height = (int)canvas.Height;

    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
         width, (int)canvas.Height,
         96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    // needed otherwise the image output is black
    canvas.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(width, height));
    canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Size(width, height)));

    renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

    //JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

    using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
    {
        encoder.Save(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    string head = SetHeadForPrintImage(sensor);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    g.DrawString(head, new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new PointF(200, 0));

    bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
    bmp.Save(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");
    bmp.Dispose();
    File.Delete(filename);
}
```

Bitmap objects often hold a reference to the file that they are read from , and the file may not be deleted while the bitmap is open (this differs depending on which file format the image is; it may be safe deleting the  origninal file of a png but not jpg etc).
You should always call Dispose() on objects that are IDisposable.
The best thing would be if you could put the bmp object in a using statement

Comment: Again I have this exception

Comment: Which line is it now that throws? Is it line `File.Delete(filename);` or is it `File.Delete(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");`?

Comment: both. Sometimes File.Delete(filename);, sometimes File.Delete(@".\Print\" + sensor + ".jpg");

Comment: I put one try catch block and now is not throw me exception. And make to run code every 200 milisecond. and now is working, but I think this is not really solve the problem.

Comment: I moved the delete ...sensor... to the beginning of the method. It might work better? Some questions: Are files often written with the same names? Are there several threads running?

Comment: Does the code still throw?
In which context does this run; as a windows program, web server; windows service etc?

Comment: In the last row is throw me the same exception. I change my logic and now is not throw me exception. If is not working maybe the logic is not good. And I change my method and now is working better.